# Observable Data Store Service with different Data Sets In Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to follow the "Observable data store" pattern in Angular 2 (detailed in this blog post from [Angular University](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/)) From what I understand, this means that, if I have a service called `TodoStore,` I would subscribe to `TodoStore.items$` so I could get all the latest updates for my to-do list in real time (as other components add, remove, or edit `Todos`.

However, what if I have two components side-by-side that display different `Todo`lists, filtered on the server-side? One might display `Todo`s due today while another would show `Todo`s due on a user-selected date.

In this case, I would not be able to use the same `TodoStore`, as both would be fetching different data from the server. How do I handle sharing this service between these two components? My urge is to go back to an angular1-style `getToDoList()` service method, but then I'm storing state inside a single component and can't possibly share data between multiple components without making extra API calls.

Comment: Is it two different components side-by-side or two instances of the same component side-by-side?  Please add some code, at least the minimum needed to clarify your question.

Comment: Why don't you use something like `TodoStore.getItemsFromList(name)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lists really **have** to be filtered server-side and you have an unknown number of simultaneously displayed lists and a new server-request has to me made for each list + filter, then it is perfectly possible that using a single observable (`TodoStore.items$`) might not be a viable solution here and maybe some kind of `getTodoList(forFilter)` might be easier/quicker to implement.

Remeber: There is no such thing as *"The perfect solution for all cases."*

However: Even in this case you could use a store, which could something like this:

```
interface ITodoListDictionary {
    [key: string]: Todo[];
}

@Injectable()
export class TodoStore {
    todoLists$: BehaviorSubject<ITodoListDictionary> = new BehaviorSubject<ITodoListDictionary>({});

    getListByKey(key: string): Observable<Todo[]> {
        return this.todoLists$
            .pluck(key)
            .distinctUntilChanged() // optional, so you only get the update if there is an actually new list
            .share();
    }

    // this would be called whenever the rest-response for a given list arrives
    setListByKey(key: string, list: Todo[]): void {
        this.todoLists$.take(1)
            .do(dict => {
                const newDict = Object.assign({}, dict, {[key]: list});
                // if you are using TS2.1 you could also use:
                // const newDict = {...dict, {[key]: list}};
                this.todoLists$.next(newDict);
            })
            .subscribe();
    }
}
```

...and in your template you could use it like this

```
<todo *ngFor="let todo of todoStore.getListByKey(someKey) | async" todo="todo"></todo>
```

Please keep in mind that is just **one** possible solution out of **many** - without seeing your actual application-flow it is hard to tell which might be the best solition.